# using electron api from react component

Tags: reactjs, electron

I'm using electron and react, the react app was created with the create-react-app boilerplate. I need to use the electron API to open an external link, but this task is achieve from a react component. I imported the remote electron inside the react component(in order to get access to the current window.) but that gave me an error

```
const {remote} = require("electron")
```

The error is raised from electron itself, from `node_modules/electron/index.js` and the problem is with *fs* module, it says:

`TypeError: fs.existsSync is not a function`

This error is showed in the electron windows.

Comment: https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/7300 might be a similar issue. Solution was to use window.require('electron')

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks

Comment: No problem. I would recommend reading that whole thread though, because depending on your build environment it can have effects on other parts of your app. I would do a thorough test of everything before moving forward to make sure it's not interfering with anything else

Answer (score 2):

For typescript:

```
import { IpcRenderer } from 'electron';

declare global {
  interface Window {
    require: (module: 'electron') => {
      ipcRenderer: IpcRenderer
    };
  }
}

const { ipcRenderer } = window.require('electron');
```

See https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/9920

Answer (score 1):

Encountered the same problem using `react-create-app`.

The fix, using `window.require` on the React side instead of `import`

```js
const electron = window.require("electron")
```

and on the Electron side, when creating `BrowserWindow` add `nodeIntegration: true` as follow

```js
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 900,
    height: 680,
    webPreferences: { nodeIntegration: true }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

### The answers above are not current.

**Here is the correct answer:**

Since Electron v12, setting `nodeIntegration: true` has no affect. Instead, you need to set `contextIsolation: false`:

```js
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    // ...
    webPreferences: {
        contextIsolation: false,
    }
})
```

https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/7300#issuecomment-799093768